# Como ler um arquivo de texto na camada INFRA.DATA de um projeto Asp.net Core - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Na camada Infra.Data, configurei as propriedades de um arquivo csv para ser copiado para o diretório de saída a pasta "bin" e eu gostaria de lê-lo usando a classe StreamReader. Após ser copiado para a pasta bin o caminho fica assim: \bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\DataLoad\Source\codigos_postais.csv.

Como faço para informar o caminho "DataLoad\Source\codigos_postais.csv" e ler o arquivo a partir da pasta bin do meu projeto, sem ter que passar o caminho completo a partir de C: "C:\user......"?

```
public class CodigoPostalInitializer
{
    public static void Initializer_Pat_1(RetaguardaContext context)
    {
        //List<CodigoPostal> codigoPostalList = new List<CodigoPostal>();
        CodigoPostal codigoPostal = null;
        Cidade cidade = null;



        if (!context.CodigoPostal.Any())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\USER\repos\retaguarda\Retaguarda\src\Retaguarda.Infra.Data\DataLoad\Source\codigos_postais.csv");

            string linha;
            while ((linha = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] dados = linha.Split(',');
                string CodigoPostal = dados[0];
                string Logradouro = dados[1];
                string Complmento = dados[2];
                string Bairro = dados[3];
                string UF = dados[4];
                string Cidade = dados[5];
                string CodigoIBGE = dados[6];

                cidade = context.Cidade.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Nome.ToUpper() == Cidade.ToUpper() && (x.Estado.UF == UF || x.CodigoIBGE == CodigoIBGE));
                codigoPostal = new CodigoPostal(CodigoPostal, Logradouro, Complmento, Bairro, cidade.Id, true);
                context.Add(codigoPostal);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

        }

        //codigoPostalList.ForEach(t => context.Add(t));

        //context.SaveChanges();

        GC.Collect(0, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(?????????);
```

Comment: Através do IHostingEnvironment vc usa o ContentRootPath, porém para não adicionar a referência do ASP.NET Core na sua camada de infra, terá que passar isso quando tiver injetando. Se puder fornecer a forma que vc está rodando esse seed talvez seja possível te fornecer uma resposta mais assertiva.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @Rafael. Atualizei o Post :)

Comment: Fiz esse código como eu uso o seed baseado em um arquivo, não tem todos os tratamentos, mas veja se isso resolve que eu elaboro uma resposta. https://github.com/superrfm/aspnetcoreweb_efcore